# SunMSCAPI returns no certificates

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, mscapi

We're trying to use SunMSCAPI to retrieve a certificate from the Windows certificate store. I've created a very simple example that loads the keystore and lists the available aliases. However, the code doesn't list anything, even though I see two personal certificates in the keystore.

On my own system it works fine by the way, but on the actual application server we will be using it doesn't list anything.

Below is the code I'm using

```
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    ks.load(null, null);

    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();

    System.out.println("Listing aliases " + ks.size());
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String ka = aliases.nextElement();

        System.out.println(ka + " " + ks.isKeyEntry(ka));
    }
```

And a screenshot of the certificate store on the application server. As you can see, I expected two aliases to be listed (but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong location?):
[image]

Comment: Any exception while listing the aliases? And please provide the specs of you machine and your application server.

Comment: No exceptions. Just an empty list. My laptop is running Windows 10. On the server we have Windows 2012R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the computer certificates, not user certificates. `Windows-MY` keystore only can use the personal user certificates.

You can explore the personal certificates using *Manage user certificates* (`certmgr` )from control panel instead of *Manage computer certificates* (`certIm`)

[image: certmgr]

Comment: Yes, that was it. My personal user certificates store was empty. Thanks for the clarification.